# Using Yup and Formik in custom component with multiple fields

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have a form in React that includes, among other things, a field for password and a field to confirm the password. Pretty common stuff. I'm using [Formik](https://formik.org/) and [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) for my form/validation along with [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/). I want to break these two fields off into their own component so that I can reuse them in several places in my app. I'm having trouble figuring out how to use Formik and Yup inside a  component that I can drop into a form. There are loads of examples for writing [components with only a single field](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial#leveraging-react-context), and I could easily do this if I didn't want to use Formik/Yup *within* my component - but that would kind of defeat the purpose.

Here's an extraction of just the relevant password code to give you an idea of what I'm working with. I would like to be able to drop this, validation and all, into another form.

```
const initialValues = {
  password1: "",
  password2: ""
};

const passwordRex = /(?=.*[\d!@#$%^&]+)(?![.\n])(?=.*\w).*$/i;

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  password1: Yup.string()
    .label("Password")
    .min(8)
    .matches(passwordRex, "Password must include letters and at least one number or symbol")
    .required(),
  password2: Yup.string()
    // Ensures password2 matches password1. Sauce: https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/90#issuecomment-392571270
    .oneOf([Yup.ref("password1")], "Passwords must match")
    .required(),
});

class Registration extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        component={({
// ...
        }) => {
                      <FormGroup widths="equal">
                        <FormField
                          error={touched.password1 && errors.password1}
                          required
                        >
                          <label>Password</label>
                          <Field
                            type="password"
                            name="password1"
                          />
                        </FormField>
                        <FormField
                          error={touched.password2 && errors.password2}
                          required
                        >
                          <label>Confirm Password</label>
                          <Field
                            type="password"
                            name="password2"
                          />
                        </FormField>
                      </FormGroup>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What about using field-level validation in Formik? https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#validate-1

You could create a new component wrapped in a <Field /> component, then create your own validation functions so it's separate from the Yup schema.

Comment: @JoshuaMcNabb - it gets it closer, but how would you display the error state (`error={touched.password1 && errors.password1}` in the sample code) in the component, especially considering the two fields have separate error states?